# Android Service - Transfer Data to Activity on finish

Tags: android, service, background, get, gps

Well this is pretty simple for you guys (I HOPE) , 
I have a service which sends a Location Request to the google play services , fused location provider api which in turn returns updates of location every now and then based on distance/interval in the onLocationChanged() call back provided by the same api. (stored in an arraylist)

Well , my service is a start sticky based one . With my half knowledge or full i can say that these kind of services can be destroyed and just restart the service when that happens , or does it ? idk . But if it does restart then that means that my arraylist holding n Number of locations collected will be thrown away due to re-initialization.

Is there a work around ?

Also in the service i use threads the perform tasks , i really cant seem to understand this , threads run independently right ? so that means that even before the thread executes completely , code after it will be executed simultaneously , so when do i detect that the thread completed so i can log a few values or start a new task , is there a thread call back of some kind which im not aware of ?

Thank you.